# Losing fragment on rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having a problem in my app where, even with some of the most basic code (see below), I'm losing a fragment view on rotation.

Everything starts off great:

[image: Starting in portrait]

Until you rotate:

[image: Rotated to landscape]

The story is the same the the other way as well:

[image: Starting in landscape]

[image: Rotated to portrait]

I'm not sure what is going on. I've tried to follow various tutorials and code examples, checked via logging to make sure that the fragments are being saved and restored, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private FragmentManager fragment_manager;
    private CharacterMenuFragment characterMenuFragment;
    private CharacterEditFragment characterEditFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);

        fragment_manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            characterMenuFragment = (CharacterMenuFragment) fragment_manager.getFragment(savedInstanceState, "characterMenuFragment");
            characterEditFragment = (CharacterEditFragment) fragment_manager.getFragment(savedInstanceState, "characterEditFragment");
        }

        if (characterMenuFragment == null) {
            Log.i("characterMenuFragment", "making new fragment");
            characterMenuFragment = new CharacterMenuFragment();
        } else {
            Log.i("characterMenuFragment", "re-using old fragment");
        }

        if (characterEditFragment == null) {
            Log.i("characterEditFragment", "making new fragment");
            characterEditFragment = new CharacterEditFragment();
        } else {
            Log.i("characterEditFragment", "re-using old fragment");
        }

        fragment_manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.menu_frame, characterMenuFragment).commit();
        fragment_manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, characterEditFragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        fragment_manager.putFragment(savedInstanceState, "characterMenuFragment", characterMenuFragment);
        fragment_manager.putFragment(savedInstanceState, "characterEditFragment", characterEditFragment);
    }
}
```

**CharacterEditFragment.java**

```
public class CharacterEditFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

**CharacterMenuFragment.java**

```
public class CharacterMenuFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

**content_frame.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**hello_world.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);

    fragment_manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        characterMenuFragment = (CharacterMenuFragment) fragment_manager.getFragment(savedInstanceState, "characterMenuFragment");
        characterEditFragment = (CharacterEditFragment) fragment_manager.getFragment(savedInstanceState, "characterEditFragment");
    }

    if (characterMenuFragment == null) {
        Log.i("characterMenuFragment", "making new fragment");
        characterMenuFragment = new CharacterMenuFragment();
        fragment_manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.menu_frame, characterMenuFragment).commit();
    } else {
        Log.i("characterMenuFragment", "re-using old fragment");
    }

    if (characterEditFragment == null) {
        Log.i("characterEditFragment", "making new fragment");
        characterEditFragment = new CharacterEditFragment();
        fragment_manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, characterEditFragment).commit();
    } else {
        Log.i("characterEditFragment", "re-using old fragment");
    }
}
```

Move the fragment managers into the applicable if statements above. You're just making sure to reuse the existing fragment and only creating one if the fragment doesn't exist.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much, didn't realize the restoration process would put them back on it's own.